# Windows 10 Shutdown is Slow After November Update

Tags: windows-10

Yesterday, I installed the November Update for Windows 10 on my computer, and since then, I've been having issues with my shutdowns taking an abnormally long amount of time. When I shut down my computer, the screen will shut off about a minute later, but the machine itself remains powered on for several more minutes before completely shutting down.

When I try restarting, I run in to the same issue: the screen will shut off, but the machine will remain running for several minutes before the reboot begins. I've read online that this issue can be resolved by disabling fastboot, and although it has helped improve my shutdown and startup performance, the issue is still present. Prior to installing the November Update, I didn't have any issues with shutdown or reboot times. I am running the 64-bit Professional version of Windows 10.

What can I do to resolve the issue?

**Update:** I used the Media Creation Tool to reinstall Windows 10 while leaving my files and programs installed. I observed the reboot issue even during the reinstall, and it is still an issue now. I also tried turning off Intel Virtualization as suggested [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Windows-10-will-not-shut-down-completely-Power-light-stays/m-p/5199883/highlight/true#M74100).

**Update 2:** I also tried downgrading my IMEI driver as was suggested [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Windows-10-will-not-shut-down-completely-Power-light-stays/m-p/5298051/highlight/true#M76856) as well as in several other locations.

Comment: Install the Win10 WPT (part of the SDK: https://t.co/et4jctp0uW) and run the following command: http://pastebin.com/RFRkuc81. Share the compressed file, so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Just want to let you know that I've started the installation process and will post again with the results when they are ready.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The output contained two ETL files, so I've included both of them in the archive file. - https://www.dropbox.com/s/33j84y3mvdpprio/shutdowntrace.7z?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a summary of the shutdown by running `D:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\xperf.exe" -i shutdown_BASE+LATENCY+DISPATCHER+FILE_IO+FILENAME+DISK_IO_INIT_1.etl -o summary_shutdown.xml -a shutdown` shows this:

[image]

Windows needs 38.4 seconds to shut down and the longest part is to shutdown the kernel (14 seconds).

But I also see that 3 services hang (Terminal Services, Defender and WLAN service). Try a different AV suite and stop TeamViewer before doing a shutdown.

But I can't see from the trace, that Windows takes several minutes to shutdown. Maybe this is a BIOS/UEFI issue. Look if there is a newer BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: There is no new BIOS version available, so I'll give the service killing thing a try first.

Comment: I tried the service-kill thing, but it didn't work. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: is hibernation/resume slow?

Comment: Hibernation is slow, but resuming does not seem to be a problem, as it came up almost instantly.

Comment: ok, run this command to trace he slow hibernation. looks like you use the fastBoot which does a logoff + hibernate. My command traced the normal full shutdown: http://pastebin.com/Y632phPU

Comment: I have fast-boot turned off in the settings because if I have it turned on, it causes problems with the VPN server I host on my computer, so I'm not sure why it's acting like I have it enabled. Here's the archive file containing the results of the trace of the hibernation - https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmsugdk2ptd0t2u/HibernateTrace.7z?dl=0

Comment: ok, in the hibernation the device **"USB\VID_0CF3&PID_311D\Alaska_Day_2006"/Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter** take 84 seconds to sleep. and this causes the slowdown.  If if you don't use fastBoot I have no other idea. the normal shutdown is done under 1 minute.

Comment: Great! It worked! It looks like I'll have to disable my Bluetooth hardware whenever I'm not using it. Would you have any idea what "Alaska_Day_2006" is?

Comment: This is the hardware ID and I read the value from the ETL

Comment: I get an error on the `-i` argument: `xperf: error: shutdown_BASE+LATENCY+DISPATCHER+FILE_IO+FILENAME+DISK_IO_INIT_1.etl: Unknown (0x8000ffff)`. I assume I'm missing some trace files?

Comment: @MrCalvin maybe the file is damaged. capture a new one or try to open the etl in [WPA and apply the FullBoot.Shutdown.wpaprofile](https://superuser.com/a/1190547/174557) to see also details about shutdown.

Comment: I just installed the Performance- and Accessment Toolkit, but no .etl files seem to be installed (at least not in the program folder). Where does these .etl files come from?

Comment: you need to capture the shutdown ETL first wit xbootmgr.exe or WPRUI.exe @MrCalvin

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all the files under:

```
C:\Windows\Prefetch
```

And just leave `Layout.ini`, then reboot. The process might take some time.

After that, when the system has started again, try to shut down.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have anything to backup the claim that this speeds up the shutdown?

Comment: yap 1)i've tried on my own laptop, when i had the same problem two days ago. And solved.
2)i've received the same advice directly from microsoft

Comment: This did not work for me unfortunately.