# How to know what Windows 7 is doing before shutdown/reboot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown

I have a core i3 notebook running Windows 7 32-bit, and sometimes it takes a long time to shutdown or reboot.  I have disabled Windows Update, and have not installed any new software or drivers.  So, there is no reason to take about 5 minutes to shutdown or reboot.

How can I determine what it is doing? BTW, I see the blinking light for hard disk activity during these time.

Comment: trace shutdown with WPT: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247

Comment: have you ever analyzed shutdown with WPRUI/WPA?

Comment: i see you accepted the troll answer. So I'm out here *tactical facepalm*

Comment: @magicandre1981 you do a great post too, I just forgot to +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this can be enabled through Group Policy.

If you're running a Professional edition of Windows, the setting is found in the Group Policy Editor: Type **gpedit.msc** in the Start menu search box (or Cortana) and hit Enter, then go to **Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System** and is called **Verbose vs normal status messages** for Windows 7 and earlier and **Display highly detailed status messages** for Windows 8 and later. Enable the setting to show verbose information while shutting down or starting up.

If you're running a Home version of Windows, open Registry Editor, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion‌​\Policies\System`, and set the key `verbosestatus` to 1, creating it as a DWORD value if it does not exist.

(Credit for the specifics of this process goes to [The Windows Club](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-verbose-status-message-windows).)

Comment: I tried this but no luck, nothing more than "Windows is shutting down" or "Turning off PC" is displayed during this time.

Comment: this is not really an answer. to see what Windows does use WPT to trace shutdown in detail.

Answer (score 4):

Install the `Windows Performance Toolkit`, part of Windows 10 SDK ([Build 15086, last version that works on Windows 7](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771)).

Run `WPRUI.exe`, select **First Level**, under  Resource select **CPU usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Shutdown**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1**

[image]

and click to `start`.

After reboot, open the ETL with WPA.exe. In WPA.exe, click on Profiles->Apply->"Browse Catalog" and select `FullBoot.Shutdown.wpaprofile`.

Now you see this overview how long shutdown takes:

[image]

In this sample it takes 8s to shutdown. 2s are needed to close the user session (were 1.2s were spend to kill onedrive.exe) and shutting down the windows kernel/services takes 5s.

Look at your data to see where Windows spends most of the time. If you see disk activity during shutdown, analyze the ETL for [DiskIO](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis) and [FileIO](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-45-WPT-File--Registry-Analysis).

Comment: What if you know the reason is one of the following, occurs at random, and you cant fix them: windows update, new stuck windows update, crappy disk backup software, a new piece of hardware you just tried. How can you prevent altogether a blue screen that has a chance of keeping your machine either locked for hours or stuck until you force restart?

Comment: @Spectraljump I can't understand the relevance to my answer. if you get a BSOD during shutdown ask a question if you can't [analyze the dmp on your own](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)

Comment: Sorry for misleading, "blue screen" was not referring to "bluescreen" or "BSoD". Was referring to the screen that is blue and you get stuck with when all you want is quickly restart or shut down your laptop/PC. Your solution is great but solves one thing after the fact, does not prevent the inevitable new ones.

Comment: @Spectraljump this is an analyzer, not preventer.