# Windows 10 - Slow shutdown

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10,Home edition.

I always had a fast shutdown,now it takes minutes.

I'm not an expert and I don't know if this can be the reason,but few days ago I received the "Fall Creator" update.

Can,please,someone help me to understand what can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Was fast shutdown enabled before, and now it's disabled? Or there's some programs running now that are very slow to stop, maybe checking what runs automatically & in the background, and stopping some, would help

Comment: @Xen2050,I didn't know that "fast shutdown"can be enabled.Can you,please,explain to me how to do?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how, but I know it causes problems when trying to access a win filesystem from linux. But I'm sure a web search for [windows 10 enable fast shutdown](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+10+enable+fast+shutdown&t=hg&ia=web) will help, with results like https://superuser.com/questions/957081/how-to-enable-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10 or search windows' own control panel? It looks like they might change the name or have related settings like "fast startup" or "hibernation"? I'd still check the auto-running and background processes, and stop those you don't always need

Comment: I found https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-is-very-slow-to-shutdown/fb35a679-c9b8-4a97-95c4-39c60e218130?auth=1. It's for Windows 7, but it might be worth a shot.

As @Xen2050 said, you may have some background tasks that are tying up the shutdown processes. Try booting in safe mode and seeing if you still see the problem.

Comment: [analyze the shutdown](https://superuser.com/a/1190547/174557) with WPRUI/WPA. For Windows 10, use the [last SDK 16299](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Comment: @magicandre1981,finally I fund my question,thank you for your suggestion.Before I didn't find your post, after many searches.Now,after 2/3 days of slow shutdown,I don't know how,the shutdown is normal.I'll keep your precious advice if it happen again.Would you be so kind to give me your opinion about an other topic,I'll send a comment from the post I made time ago.Thank you

Comment: which other topic? ‍♂️

Comment: @magicandre1981,if you,please,want to take a look to"Windows 10 - All the desktop icons shifted on the left side after startup".Thank you